# A non-programmers guide to programming

Tags: android

Okay so I am a very low level programmer and happy to admit it.  I can write simple programs things like VB and python etc given the basic syntax.  I want to write simple programs for android, for instance a calculator that handles feet and inches and a program that simply searches a database of products and tells me the details of them.  Is there a simple solution where I can drag and drop some buttons and text boxes and execute code or do I have to learn the whole gui drawing code and start from scratch?  If I do have to start from scratch is there a book out there that doesn't assume that I know any of the advanced coding techniques or do I have to learn the whole language and then learn the SDK?  I want to be able to write a program quick and dirty, here are the variables here's the formula, do your thing...

Comment: note that low-level means something completely different! in your case, you're a _very_ high level programmer and are asking for something of even higher level! :-)

Answer (score 6):

[Android App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/).

The problem with this approach is that you'll learn how to make apps in App Inventor, but not learn how to program Java nor how to program Android.  It may be useful as a first stepping stone though, or if you really don't want to get your hands too dirty.

Comment: @dbyrne: just make sure you remove your cat from the keyboard before you begin.

Answer (score 1):

Android App Inventor can do exactly what you want. I've done something similar with it.

One month and a half ago, it took some of my students (and some other random people) about two weeks to get the initial invite (once they had put themselves on the general waiting list). Since the form for the waiting list is still in effect, I assume it will take around the same waiting time in your case, or may be even less.

A couple of caveats thought: You need an Android phone to run your 'Android App Inventor' App (it won't run in the emulator). Android App Inventor doesn't give you access to the generated code (they have no plans to, besides they're not using java for the generated code anyway). App Inventor won't let you publish on the Market (although, they do have plans to add that capability, for now if you want your friends to install your app, it can give you a QRcode for it, or give you the apk file to share with them).

While you're waiting for your invite, I'd suggest you try out Android Scripting

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/

Scan the QRcode on that page (it's not on the Market yet). Install the SL4A app. Once SL4A is running, press on the menu key > select 'Add' > select Python. Once that's running, I recommend you run the test.py to see what kind of GUI intents can be launched directly from your phone python shell. The SL4A project is still very much alpha quality, but I'd say it's worth playing around with (especially in Python, since Python seems to be currently the most mature scripting environment supported on there, it actually supports a zillion other scripting languages).

Another thing you can do, from the Market this time, is to download the 'AndroidShell Lite' app. run the app, press the 'Local Console' button, and play around with that. I suspect that AndroidShell is using a version of the SL4A, but unlike SLA4, it can not be run in the emulator, the code doesn't seem to be open source, it doesn't support python (only beanshell which is just as easy actually), but it has much better documentation at least. That's why I'm recommending that you try out both 'AndroidShell Lite' and SL4A. Each has different strengths.

Answer (score 0):

I believe App Inventor is what you are looking for. It is not designed for complex apps but can be helpfull for simple apps.

https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=youngandroid&passive=true&nui=1&continue=http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/ode/Ya.html&followup=http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/ode/Ya.html

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you do the following:
1. Improve your JAVA programming skill. Reading material: "Think In Java"
 
2. Improve basic Android programming skill: any entry level android book

Make sure when you go through the material, 
do your best to design and implement some useful projects, and publish to the market if possible.